# Is there a delay between a SET and a GET with the same key in Redis?

Tags: c, nginx, redis, delayed-execution

I have three processes on one computer:

1. A test (T)
2. A nginx server with my own module (M) --- the test starts and stops this process between each test case section
3. A Redis server (R), which is always running --- the test does not handle the start/stop sequence of this service (I'm testing my nginx module, not Redis.)

Here is a diagram of the various events:

```
T    M    R
|    |    |
O-------->+   FLUSHDB
|    |    |
+<--------O   (FLUSHDB acknowledge as successful)
|    |    |
O-------->+   SET key value
|    |    |
+<--------O   (SET acknowledge as successful)
|    |    |
O--->+    |   Start nginx including my module
|    |    |
|    O--->+   GET key
|    |    |
|    +<---O   (SUCCESS 80% and FAILURE 20%)
|    |    |
```

The test clears the Redis database with `FLUSHDB` then adds a key with `SET key value`. The test then starts nginx including my module. There, once in a while, the nginx module `GET key` action fails.

Note 1: I am not using the `ASync` implementation of Redis.

Note 2: I am using the C library `hiredis`.

Is it possible that there would be a delay between a `SET` and a following `GET` with the same key which would explain that this process would fail once in a while? Is there a way for me to ensure that the `SET` is really done once the `redisCommand()` function returns?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** if I run one such test and the `GET` fails in my nginx module, the key appears in my Redis:

```
redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "8b95d48d13e379f1ccbcdfc39fee4acc5523a"
127.0.0.1:6379> GET "8b95d48d13e379f1ccbcdfc39fee4acc5523a"
"the expected value"
```

So the

```
SET "8b95d48d13e379f1ccbcdfc39fee4acc5523a" "the expected value"
```

worked as expected. Only the `GET` failed and I would assume that it is because it somehow occurred too quickly. Any idea how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no delay between set and get. What you are doing should work.

Try running the monitor command in a separate window. When it fails - does the set command come before/after the get command?

Comment: That is a very cool feature. `redis-cli monitor` Thanks for the info. So far, I've not been able to see it fail but that's just the beginning of the day for me.

Comment: Okay! I found my bug. nginx is not 100% systemd (at least in Ubuntu 16.04) ready as it may return before the PID file is created. So the child process must be creating the PID file and the parent doesn't wait to make sure it is done properly...